# Ember- Doing async action in a loop without promises

Tags: asynchronous, ember.js, promise

I'm wondering if given example could meet racing condition on a real server, does work on localhost. Given situation- user deletes a few person from a form ( lets say studyForm and studyPersons ) Ive added personToDelete to an array an later on- Edit Action im deleting them in a loop

```
 // A punch of persons chosen to be deleted
self.markedForDeleted.forEach(function(trashed){
                trashed.destroyRecord();
 });

 this.get('person').save().then(personEditSuccess, personEditFailure);
```

Should i edit it like this ?

```
var onDeleteSuccess = function(wasAnyToDelete){
   if (wasAnyToDelete){
    deletedPersons ++;
   }
   if(deletedPersons === lengthOfAllPersons) { 
     this.get('person').save().then(personEditSuccess, personEditFailure);
   }
};

// A punch of persons chosen to be deleted
self.markedForDeleted.forEach(function(trashed){
                trashed.destroyRecord().then(onDeleteSuccess, onDeleteFailure);
 });
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't tell what question you're actually asking or what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @jfriend00 I've form that works locally, but could there be a condition, a conflict when im doing async stuff like that on real environment when real users start using the system ? Which of the better given example is better? Is there a way to do this without "counters". In the latest example Im deleting records one by one, after counter hits deleted === toDelete Im moving on

Comment: You can use `Promise.all` (RSVP.all?) on an array of promises to wait for all of them at once.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum are you willing to refacto that deleting forEach using promise.all ? =)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Added rsvp all. something like this ?!'

Comment: You might also want to put the `save()` there somewhere I'm not sure I haven't used Ember in a year - does it work?

Comment: deleteRecord.save() works dat way

Comment: Cool, please add an answer explaining how you solved it then :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Added some =)

Comment: As an answer please, and not a part of the question :)

Answer (score 1):

Working and currently using

```
Ember.RSVP.all(personsToDelete.invoke('destroyRecord')).then(deletePersonSuccess, deletePersonFailure);
```